# Unit Testing Jest in Reactjs Component state

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Hello :) I'm starting to learn **Unit Testing** using **JEST & Enzyme**

on my version (already done) of "Color Guessing Game" using with **Reactjs**, 
but when I started to test my Square Component I can't even test my color state value and my color state when clicked (clickSquare function)...

and I can't find much resources about it, can you see what's wrong, and how can I test my Square Component?

**Square.js Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';



class Square extends Component {




constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: undefined
    }
    this.clickSquare = this.clickSquare.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.color) {
      this.setState({
        color: this.props.color
      })
    }
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    //results in the parent component to send updated props,, 
    //whenever the propositions are updated in the parent, runs this
    //to update the son as well
    this.setState({
      color: props.color
    })

  }

  clickSquare() {
    if (this.state.color === this.props.correctColor) {
      this.props.gameWon(true);
      console.log('correct', this.state.color)

    } else {
      this.setState({
        color: 'transparent'
      })
      //    this.props.gameWon(false);
      console.log('wrong')

    }
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div className='square square__elem'
        style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.color }}
        onClick={this.clickSquare}>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Square;
```

**Square.test.js Testing:**

```
import React from 'react';

import Square from '../components/Square/Square';

import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';


describe('Square component', () => {

    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => wrapper = shallow(
        <Square
            color={undefined}
            clickSquare={jest.fn()}
        />
    ));


    it('should render correctly', () => expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot());

    it('should render a <div />', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find('div.square.square__elem').length).toEqual(1);
    });

    it('should render the value of color', () => {
        wrapper.setProps({ color: undefined});
        expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual('transparent');
      });

});
```

> Expected value to equal:
>         "transparent"
>       Received:
>         {"color": undefined}
>
> ```
> Difference:
>
>   Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received object.
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you're not so far from the solution. :)

The only issue is that between the parentheses in the expression `wrapper.state()`, you don't pass any argument - that's why you receive the whole object instead of a single value. That being said, you should do the following in this case:

```
it('should render the value of color', () => {
   wrapper.setProps({ color: undefined});
   expect(wrapper.state('color')).toEqual('transparent');
});
```

Notice the usage of `wrapper.state('color')`.

---

**EDIT**

Based on your comment below, I didn't realize that the `transparent` value is set via a click event.

Here is the full test suite that should be verified by Jest:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Square from '../components/Square/Square';

describe('<Square />', () => {
   let wrapper;

   beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(<Square color={undefined} />); // Here it's not necessary to mock the clickSquare function.
   });

   it('should render the value of color', () => {
      wrapper.setProps({ color: undefined });
      wrapper.find('div').simulate('click'); // Simulating a click event.

      expect(wrapper.state('color')).toEqual('transparent');
   });
});
```

Comment: yess! thanks, that makes sense! I have to change as well the toEqual('transparent') to toEqual(undefined) and maybe after that I have to teste the setState change, Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have extended the answer above with an example. Please take a look on it and also approve the answer if it's ok to you. :)

Comment: Correct!! Yess, exactly I was missing also that "simulating a click event", thank you so much for your help! :D